# Consider an N x N matrix A with a determinant of 180, and which only has integer eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider an $N \times N$ matrix $A$ with a determinant of $180$, and which only has integer eigenvalues. What is the MAXIMUM possible number of distinct eigenvalues that $A$ can have?

I have solved this question and wanted to check if my answer is correct.

Since we know that $det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_n$,

and $180=2^2\times3^2\times5$,

$det(A)=-1\times1\times-2\times3\times5\times6$

So the MAXIMUM possible number of distinct eigenvalues that $A$ can have is 6.

Could you see if this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Why not $-1\times1\times-2\times2\times-3\times3\times-5$?

Comment: Wow, yeah you're right! Thanks!